# Snake game - random number generator for food tiles

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to make a 16x16 LED Snake game using Arduino (C++).
I need to assign a random grid index for the next food tile.
What I have is a list of indices that are occupied by the snake (snakeSquares).

So, my thought is that I need to generate a list of potential foodSquares.  Then I can pick a random index from that list, and use the value there for my next food square.

I have some ideas for this but they seem kind of clunky, so I was looking for some feedback.  I am using the Arduino LinkedList.h library for my lists in lieu of stdio.h (and random() in place of rand()):

1. Generate a list (foodSquares) containing the integers [0, 255] so that the indices correspond to the values in the list (I don't know of a quick way to do this, will probably need to use a for loop).
2. When generating list of snakeSquares, set foodSquares[i] = -1.  Afterwards, loop through foodSquares and remove all elements that equal -1.
3. Then, generate a random number randNum from [0, foodSquares.size()-1] and make the next food square index equal to foodSquares[randNum].

So I guess my question is, will this approach work, and is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Potential approach that won't require more lists:

- Calculate random integer representing number of steps.
- Take head or tail as a starting tile.
- For each step move at random free adjacent tile.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand it completely  your question as some of those points are quite waste of processor time (*i.e.* point 1 and 2). But, the first point could be solved quite easily in `n` proportional complexity as follows:

```
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    // assuming there is a list of food_squares
    food_squares[i] = i;
}
```

Then to the second point you would have to set every `food_square` to `-1`, for what? Anyway. A way you could implement this would be as VTT has said and I will describe it further:

1. Take a random number between `[0..255]`.
2. Does it is one the snake_squares? If so, back to one, else, go to three.
3. This is the same as your third point, use this *random number* to set the position of the food in `food_square` (`food_square[random_number] = some_value`).

Comment: I considered your approach in 1., but my concern was that this requires generating the random number multiple times.  As the game progresses, there will be less and less free squares and this process would be wasteful.  Also, I don't see how this is the same as what VTT suggested.

The point of setting the foodSquares to -1 is to mark them for deletion.  That way, the only grid indices that are left in the list are in fact free squares.

I also already suggested a for loop might be used to accomplish filling the foodSquares list in (1), I was looking for a shorter method if possible.

Comment: Just set `food_square` to -1 whenever the top of the snake currently is and you won't have any problem, if that square happens to have a food you just check it and increment snake size or/and pontuation.